# How to make a docker container send an HTTP request to another container running in same network

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot

I have two apps -- app1 is running on `localhost:8081`. app2 is running on `localhost:8082`. App1 is makes an HTTP GET request to app2, and app2 returns a simple json response.  This all works just fine when running both apps locally on my mac, since I'm having app1 send a GET request to "`http://localhost:8082`".

But when containerizing both of these apps (and running them on the same network), what url should app1 be sending the GET command to? It's hard-coded as "`http://localhost:8082`", and the `8082` port is exposed in the app2 container, but communication isn't happening.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two containers running in the same network via **docker-compose**, you can perform the request to their specified **name** in the docker-compose.yml file. If not using docker-compose, you can name the containers using the `--name` flag with the `docker run` command.